# What is the difference between the FreeBSD flags, immutable and unlink?

Tags: permissions, security, freebsd

What are the differences or similarities among the FreeBSD flags, simmutable/uimmutable and sunlink/uunlink?

Reading [man chflags](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chflags&sektion=1), I see these flags:

```
schg, schange, simmutable
    set the system immutable flag (super-user only)
sunlnk, sunlink
    set the system undeletable flag (super-user only)
uchg, uchange, uimmutable
    set the user immutable flag (owner or super-user only)
uunlnk, uunlink
    set the user undeletable flag (owner or super-user only)
```

I currently understand the immutable attribute in the same way as a Linux manual page on `chattr` describes it:

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file and no data can be written to the file. Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute.

How do "immutable" and "undeletable" differ in FreeBSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manpage of the syscall [chflags(2)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chflags&sektion=2):

> ```
> SF_IMMUTABLE   The file may not be changed.
> SF_NOUNLINK    The file may not be renamed or deleted.
> [...]
> UF_IMMUTABLE   The file may not be changed.
> UF_NOUNLINK    The file may not be renamed or deleted.
> ```

The flags prefixing with **`SF_`** may only be set or unset by the super-user. The others prefixing with **`UF_`** may be set or unset by either the owner of a file or the super-user.

**Note**: If one of the `SF_` flags is set a non-super-user cannot change any flags and even the super-user can change flags only if securelevel is 0.

> The security level can be set with a sysctl(8) on the kern.securelevel variable.

Comment: So, [s/u]unlink allows for change of file contents while preventing deletion and renaming, whereas [s/u]immutable allows no change? Does [s/u]immutable also mean that no link can be created to this file, as in Linux?

Comment: @Christopher yes, but only hard links, soft links can be created anyway.